# Symfony and DDD for an old and big PHP project

Tags: php, symfony, architecture, refactoring, domain-driven-design

We have an old and big PHP application with complex business logic. Now the project almost fully consists from spaghetti-code. I plan to do a smooth migration using Symfony e.g. rewrite some features using Symfony. Also seems DDD is a good choise for the project like this. So the main idea is to make a rewriting of some features to make it more clean and easy to maintain. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the DDD principles can be applied in the context of a legacy code base refactoring. This is how we did (and are still doing it), but don't take it as a silver bullet:

---

**Phase 1 - Strategic preparations:**

1.) Use **Context Mapping** to identify **Bounded Contexts** and their integrations. Try to be agnostic towards your **current architecture**. This is actually **very hard** to do because of biases. It comes in handy if you do it with people that are no constant users of the old system.

2.) Sort the contexts by strategic value and identify your **Core Domain** (Where is the money?), eventually finding **Supporting Sub Domains** (parts of the system that support achieving your strategic goals) and **Generic Sub Domains** (things that are absolutely necessary, i.e. compliance and accounting).

3.) Bring Stakeholders, Developers and Product Owners together to form a common language, the **Ubiquitous Language** within the different **Domains** that capture the intents and capabilities of the business. **Be dogmatic about a central dictionary of these terms**, if you hear something ambiguous during discussions, resolve it and add it to the dictionary. This is an integral part of any DDD project since we are modelling the capabilities of the business, which means **the code and the stakeholders language should carry the same semantics**.

4.) **OTPIONAL**: Depending on the size and working methodologies of your organization, you might have to restructure it. Let **Conway's Law** work for you and create a certain **feature gravity** by reassigning teams and individuals to the different domains that you have identified earlier as value streams where the best and brightest should be working on the **Core Domain**. Enable direct communication interfaces between developers and stakeholders to work closely on specification and constantly distilling the Model.

---

**Phase 2 - Implementation:**

0.) If you have no experiences with such a complex refactoring, get external help (consultants) or hire experienced engineers that have done this before. Believe me, you will need it (I have learned it the hard way myself).

1.) Create a **Bubble Context** in which you are free to redesign your models and integrate it with the legacy system. There are a lot of integration patterns (you can find a nice summary of those patterns [here](http://domainlanguage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/GettingStartedWithDDDWhenSurroundedByLegacySystemsV1.pdf) and [here](http://domaindrivendesigners.com/documents/ExtendingLegacySystems.pdf). Always ask yourself if the context in question has enough strategic value and is bound to evolve over time and has to nicely respond to change in the future. In the end it is all about creating Software that is **easy to change and refactor**. Iterate, rinse and repeat. Always refactor the new code as early as you gain new insights from the business.

---

**NOTE:** Don't try to do too much. The **Bounded Context's** play very nicely as **Microservices** boundaries, but a lot of times people underestimate the complexities of a distributed system. If you don't have the availability and performance requirements that would require this architecture, then a well designed, modular monolith can be just the correct tool to get the stuff done.

---

**EDIT**

If you are interested in the Strategic part of DDD you **MUST** watch Paul Rayner's talk from DDDEU 16 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bl30X0MvT0I).

Comment: The question itself it's definitely bad for SO (too generic I guess) but I'm happy it led to such a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

DDD is a set of methodologies to facilitate team communication. It has less to do with refactoring and more to do with architecture.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this qualify for SO, anyhow the explanation would be huge. There's no "silver bullet" method here. Personally I would try to isolate components, and migrate those one by one to a or several new Symfony application(s).

DDD is not relevant there. You can find many usefull pattern/methods in Martin Fowler books, especially "Refactoring" and "Patterns of Entreprise Architecture".

Comment: DDD /can/ be very relevant to broad-scale refactoring.  The existing codebase, even in a non-consistent state, can be used to extract behaviors and create valid test scenarios as a domain is modeled.  The two systems can exist side by side, through a series of abstractions, that allow for you to build the domain out, one aggregate at a time.  It is no different than a bounded context, ultimately.  The isolation of the context makes it an ideal methodology to build a brownfield refactor on.

Comment: Your examples are valid, but such an approach is way less about DDD than many other strategies: how to set up tests, how to identify and implicate business stakeholders (in a web agency, this a big deal), refactoring methodologies... Ultimately, in such a project success, DDD will have a minor role versus all other methods. IMO then DDD should not be the first thing looked upon.

Comment: Hence, my emphasized usage of "/can/".  Without being on site, neither of us can definitively say what the value is, but DDD is just as much about the strategic patterns as the tactical patterns.  My point was if a business has seen the value in refactoring, for whatever reason, and if the team has expressed an interest in DDD, it is inappropriate to dismiss it out of hand.  Businesses have a low tolerance for introducing multiple refactors on a single project, at this scale.  Simply moving behaviors into the domain model will have large impacts to reduce complexity.